# finding methods / classes by 'some' keywords in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Is there any way to search for methods / types by just some keywords?

For example, imagine the method `GetLocalPathForOriginalFile`.  Say, doing a search for `get local original` would return that method (or a list of methods by relevance).

Visual Studio 2012 does this from the 'Search Solution Explorer', but only up to classes.  It does not search method names.

I am also using Resharper v7 and Visual Studio 2012, so if that does it it would be good as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Alt-Shift-T (if you are using VS keyboard scheme in ReSharper) and type `Get*Local*Original`.

Comment: That just brings up the Unit Test Session window for me

Comment: That's genius - it's going on my blog post! http://levelnis.co.uk/blog/the-wonderful-world-of-resharper

Comment: perfect! Didn't know it allowed wildcards, and I had already given that a try :)

Comment: Window is also accessed via Resharper > Navigate > Go To Symbol - Just in case the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: @levelnis Another thing I discovered is that you can use the wildcard functionality even directly from code, if you are using Resharper's Intellisense.  For example, typing `I*Item` will show you in Intellisense even `IMediaItem`. Brilliant! :)